# Updating table data inside Jinja template with jquery function

Tags: jquery, flask, jinja2

First time my page gets loaded the table get generated as follows (I iterate `blocks` that get passed as part of the request):

```
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>Previous Hash</th>
            <th>Timestamp</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Hash</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for block in blocks %}
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{block.index}}</th>
            <td>{{block.previous_hash[0:10]}}</td>
            <td>{{block.timestamp}}</td>
            <td>{{block.data}}</td>
            <td>{{block.hash[0:10]}}</td>
          </tr>
          {% else %}
          <li><em>Unbelievable.  No entries here so far</em>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

Now I want that table to be reloaded without refreshing the page within a jquery function. How do i do that?

P.S.
I dont have problems updating simple elements like text fields:

```
$('#banner').text('new banner text')
```

But this table thing is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how you want to handle this.
one way would be to have a view to return a html page containing the table data:

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row">{{block.index}}</th>
    <td>{{block.previous_hash[0:10]}}</td>
    <td>{{block.timestamp}}</td>
    <td>{{block.data}}</td>
    <td>{{block.hash[0:10]}}</td>
</tr>
```

you send the data using something like this:

```
 return jsonify({"result": render_template('row.html', block=block)})
```

then, you could use your jquery code to update the table and append the new row to it.

other way would be to fetch the whole table over and over again with the new data being thrown around. i would and am using the first way by the way.